# Mysql array and data

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql query and PHP code that I'm using to get users from the database that meet certain criteria is:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT a2.id, a2.name FROM members a2 JOIN room f ON f.myid = a2.id
WHERE f.user = 1 AND a2.status ='7' UNION SELECT  a2.id, a2.name FROM members a2 
JOIN room f ON f.user = a2.id WHERE f.myid = 1  AND a2.status ='7' GROUP BY id") 
or die(mysql_error());

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$temp[] = '"'.$r[0].'"';
}
$thelist = implode(",",$temp);
```

The query that follows get the list of members with new galleries by using array from the previous query.

```
$ft = mysql_query("SELECT id, pic1 FROM foto WHERE id IN ($thelist) AND 
pic1!='' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");

while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($ft))
{
echo $f['id']." - ".$f['pic1']."<br/>";
}
```

These queries working fine but I need to get the name for every user listed in second query. This data is in the first query in the column name. How can I get it listed beside '$f['id']." - ".$f['pic1']'?

Answer (score 0):

While I might just alter the first query to pull the galleries at the same time, or change the second query to join and get the name, you could keep the same structure and change a few things:

In the loop after the first query when building `$temp[]`, also build a lookup table of user id to user name:

```
$usernames[$r[0]] = $r[1];
```

Then in your output loop, use the id (assuming they are the same!) from the second query to call up the user name value you stored:

```
echo $f['id'] . " - " . $f['pic1'] . " - " . $usernames[$f['id']] . "<br/>";
```